# UML Design Patterns. Controller/Expert/Creator

Tags: uml

I have an UML exam coming up in a few days and have a feeling one of these topics will come up in the form of: "Explain using an example the Expert pattern".

A brief and understandable explanation is all I'm looking for - I haven't been able to find this online anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: you can find a good example of **Expert Pattern** in this [free ebook](https://www.utdallas.edu/~chung/SP/applying-uml-and-patterns.pdf) (Applying UML and Patterns, pages 221-226).

Comment: That ebook also has controller and creator patterns which were explained very well, complete with diagrams. Thanks for showing me this resource - I completely understand the concepts now.

Answer (score 0):

Information expert is a GRASP pattern, GRASP patterns are related to design principles ( see [GRASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270912/what-is-the-difference-between-gof-and-grasp-design-patterns) ) and GOF pattern are related to design. Even if GOF patterns, for me, are built with GRASP principles.

Information expert stands that the class that get the information shall get the method providing this information. See [information expert](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/f12/presentation-materials/rao.pdf)

Did you really look on the net before asking your question ?

Comment: He didn't look. My reference above was the first for "expert pattern".